# Java ScriptEngine cannot find module referenced by Javascript file

Tags: java, javascript, scriptengine

I am using Java 7, and I have the following code that uses the [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) Javascript library:

```
logger.debug("CURRENT PATH=" + Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath());
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
reader = new FileReader("webclient/common/js/jsondiffpatch.min.js");
engine.eval(reader);
```

If you look at line 48 of [jsondiffpatch.js](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch/blob/master/public/build/jsondiffpatch.js) (the uncompressed version of `jsondiffpatch.min.js`), you can see it references another module:

```
var packageInfoModuleName = '../package.json';
```

When executing the Java code, the `engine.eval(reader)` line can't find `package.json` and throws the following exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Cannot find module '../package.json' in <Unknown source> at line number 1
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:224) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at nms.server.domain.AuditManager$ConfigAuditProcessor.run(AuditManager.java:465) ~[nms.jar:na]
Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.JavaScriptException: Error: Cannot find module '../package.json' (<Unknown source>#1)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1066) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:849) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:430) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:116) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:109) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3160) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:173) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1169) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:214) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
```

The `jsondiffpatch.min.js` file is located in the `webclient/common/js` directory, and the `package.json` file is located in the `webclient/common` directory.

The `logger.debug` line printed out the following for the current working directory:

```
 CURRENT PATH=/usr/local/project/version/Software
```

So I tried copying the `package.json` file to the `/usr/local/project/version` directory, and I still got the same exception.

Why can't the ScriptEngine find the `package.json` file?

Answer (score 1):

the jsondiffpatch.js file found in /public/build is a bundle (created with browserify) intended only for using it in a browser (the `require` function called there is defined at the top of the file, it doesn't read files from disc).

I'm not familiar with Java ScriptEngine, but it looks it's not allowing a redefine of the `require` function. if it supports CommonJS, you shouldn't use the bundled version, you should require `./src/main.js` (the library main module, as pointed in `package.json`)

(Disclaimer: I'm [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) author)

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to try the *full path* of the module you want to include.

Comment: Do you mean change the var packageInfoModuleName = '../package.json'; line to be var packageInfoModuleName = '/usr/local/project/version/Software/webclient/common/package.json';? That line is in 3rd-party code, and ideally we don't want to change that, otherwise we'd have to change it every time we get a new version of the library.  Also, I just tried it, and it didn't work anyway (same exception).

Answer (score 0):

I used Java 8, Nashorn, nashorn-commonjs-modules, jsondiffpatch.js.

I deleted chalk external module and package.json from the file main.js because it's outside the scope of my Nashorn base folder.

It's work now :)

```
    public String diff() throws ScriptException {

    NashornScriptEngine engine = (NashornScriptEngine) new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    FilesystemFolder rootFolder = FilesystemFolder.create(new File("C:\\Users\\Maxime\\Documents\\writecontrol\\default\\gateway\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\bower_components\\jsondiffpatch\\src"), "UTF-8");
    Module module = Require.enable(engine, rootFolder);

    try {
        ScriptObjectMirror result = (ScriptObjectMirror)  engine.eval("var jsondiffpatch = require('./main.js');" +
                " var country = {\n" +
                "                name: \"Argentina\",\n" +
                "                capital: \"Buenos Aires\",\n" +
                "                independence: new Date(1816, 6, 9),\n" +
                "                unasur: true\n" +
                "    };" +
                "var country2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(country), jsondiffpatch.dateReviver);" +
                "    country2.name = \"Republica Argentina\";\n" +
                "    country2.population = 41324992;\n" +
                "    delete country2.capital;\n" +
                "    var delta = jsondiffpatch.diff(country, country2);" +
                "print(delta.name);" +
                "print('Nashorn Hello World!');" +
                "data=JSON.stringify(delta);" +
                "var result = {delta : data};" +
                "result");

        delta = (String) result.getMember("delta");


        System.out.println(delta);

    } catch (final ScriptException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    return delta;
}
```